# xamarin Pop a DialogViewController prevents next pushed view from showing

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm trying to write a simple app for iOS using Xamarin Studio 4.0.12 (build 3).

I have a "Home" `UIViewController` that is the first to be added into the `rootNavigationController`.

Home has a button that is used to show a "Sign In" or "Create Account" view both based on `DialogViewController`. These are displayed with a call `this.NavigationController.PushViewController` in response to a Home view button press (so "this" is the Home instance).

When the user dismisses the Sign In dialog, a callback into Home is made and in that code `this.NavigationController.PopViewControllerAnimated` is made to remove the dialog from the view stack.

Then, another call to `this.NavigationController.PushViewController` is made to display details that can be seen once signed in.

**The problem is the detail view is never displayed.** I have stepped through in the debugger and can see the `NavigationController` has the appropriate views in the right order.

Here's the actual code in the callback:

```
private void OnShowSigninScreenClose(string username, string password)
{
    try
    {
        this.NavigationController.PopViewControllerAnimated(true); 
        ReceiptsScreen receiptsScreen = new ReceiptsScreen ();
        this.NavigationController.PushViewController (receiptsScreen, true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Alert ("CaptionError".Localized (), ex.Message);
    }
}
```

If I remove the call to `PopViewControllerAnimated` the detail screen is shown, but the navigation bar has a button to go back to the sign in screen. **I really want to replace the sign in screen with the details screen in the view stack.**

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Replace PushViewController with just PresentViewController.

```
this.PresentViewController(receiptsScreen,true, null);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, I'm not making that work either. It does change the way the Sign in view is displayed - it now slides up from the bottom (like a modal view?) but I don't seem to be able to dismiss it. I added a call in the Sign In view, just before the callback, like this: this.RemoveFromparentViewController(); but the sign in view never goes away.

Comment: Maybe the real answer, is that you need to present your Sign in.. via PresentViewController.. and keep your details screen un-updated until you have a valid sign-in... What you really need to understand, is that DismissViewController and PresentViewController at the end of the method.. allow for delegate {  } actions.. that you can force the next screens to pop up after your user has completed an action.

Comment: I wouldn't say this.. if I didn't have an app.. with a sign in.. for an oil industry app.  I force registration at app start.. I then force them to give their signature.. then they are free within the app to do as they wish.  By using PresentViewController, and saving local preferences.. I can control the user experience in the start up.